# quarkus, configure multiple log files without specifyng package?

Tags: logging, quarkus

I have the following application.properties on my Quarkus app named user-import:

```
#Logging
quarkus.log.level=INFO

quarkus.log.category."it.mydomain.userimport".level=INFO
quarkus.log.category."it.mydomain.userimport=,FILE_INFO,FILE_ERR

# Configure a named handler that logs to info file
quarkus.log.handler.file."FILE_INFO".enable=true
quarkus.log.handler.file."FILE_INFO".path=/tmp/user-import_info.log
quarkus.log.handler.file."FILE_INFO".level=INFO

# Configure a named handler that logs to error file
quarkus.log.handler.file."FILE_ERR".enable=true
quarkus.log.handler.file."FILE_ERR".path=/tmp/user-import_err.log
quarkus.log.handler.file."FILE_ERR".level=ERROR

# General log goes to Application file
quarkus.log.file.enable=true
quarkus.log.file.path=/tmp/user-import.log
quarkus.log.file.level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.min-level=DEBUG
```

With this configuration I can propertly produce 3 log files:

1. user-import.log (DEBUG LEVEL)
2. user-import_info.log (INFO LEVEL)
3. user-import_err.log (ERROR LEVEL)

My question is:

Am I able to reproduce the same effect without specifying application's package (ie: it.mydomain.userimport) ?

Comment: Nope, what you have done is the most consise you can get